# How to pass a variable to multiple components in React routes

Tags: reactjs, variables, routes

I am looking for a simple way to pass a variable (backend_url={backend_url}) to multiple components in React. The way that I am currently using looks very repeated.

```
<Routes>
          <Route exact path="/posts/:username/newPost" element={<CreatePost backend_url={backend_url}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/posts" element={<PostList backend_url={backend_url}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/posts/:id/" element={<PostDetail backend_url={backend_url}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/posts/:id/delete" element={<DeletePost backend_url={backend_url}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/posts/:id/update" element={<UpdatePost backend_url={backend_url}/>} />
          <Route exact path="/myPosts" element={<MyPosts />} />
</Routes>
```

Your suggestion on simpler ways would really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the React Context system to pass down the `backend_url` prop.

Inside `backendUrlContext.js` file

```
import {createContext, useContext} from "react";

const defaultBackendUrlValue = "";

const backendUrlContext = createContext(defaultBackendUrlValue);

export const BackendUrlProvider = backendUrlContext.Provider;
export const BackendUrlConsumer = backendUrlContext.Consumer;

export const useBackendUrl = () => useContext(backendUrlContext);
```

Inside routes file

```
import {BackendUrlProvider} from "backendUrlContext";

<BackendUrlProvider value={backend_url}>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/posts/:username/newPost" element={<CreatePost />} />
    <Route exact path="/posts" element={<PostList />} />
    <Route exact path="/posts/:id/" element={<PostDetail />} />
    <Route exact path="/posts/:id/delete" element={<DeletePost />} />
    <Route exact path="/posts/:id/update" element={<UpdatePost />} />
    <Route exact path="/myPosts" element={<MyPosts />} />
  </Routes>
</BackendUrlProvider>
```

Then you can access backend_url value inside any route element nested inside `BackendUrlProvider` by using the `useBackendUrl` hook

```
import {useBackendUrl} from "backendUrlContext";

function CreatePost() {
  const backendUrl = useBackendUrl();
 
 /*
   ...rest of the logic
 */
}
```

And this approach will also work in any nested child component which is not a directly nested route.